# Making text move when screen size is adjusted

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like my image & text (h1, h3, & 'laurel' image) to 'anchor' to the left-side of the screen, so that when I adjust the screen size (specifically from left-to-right), the image keeps the same padding/margin as the background image/overlay.

Currently, the image adjusts only after reaching the very end of the left side of the screen. This is causing the image to appear not centered depending on the size of the screen. [here is a visual of the issue and requested solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpagK.png)

Sorry for the long post & thank you in advance. Here is a #potato.

html section (using Hugo--thus the markdown inserts)

```
<section class="slider-invest {{ if .bg_overlay }}overly-invest{{ end }}" 
style="background-image: url('{{ .bg_image_slider | relURL }}');">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="block">
      {{ with .heading }}<h1>{{ . | markdownify }}</h1>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary1 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary2 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary3 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary4 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary5 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="{{ .laurel | relURL }}" class="laurel" alt="Img">
    </div>
    {{ with .button }}
    {{ if .enable }}
    <a href="{{ .link | relLangURL }}" class="btn-invest btn btn- 
    main animated fadeInUp">{{ .label }}</a>
    {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.slider-invest {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 180px 0 380px;
  position: relative;
  @include tablet {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    padding: 150px 0;
  }
  
  .block {
  color: #E3E3E4;
  text-align: center;

  h1 {
    color: $theme;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 1.33em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 52.5%;
    margin-top: 0%;

    @include tablet {
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    @include mobile {
      font-size: 28px;
    }

    @include mobile-xs {
      font-size: 26px;
    }
  }

  p {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: $theme;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;

    @include mobile {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }

  @include mobile {
    .btn {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
}
}

.overly-invest {
  position: relative;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    left: 7.5%;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.90;
  }
}

.invest-slider-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-right: 57%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  color: #292929;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.laurel {
  width: 38vw;
  height: auto;
  left: 0%;
  padding-top: 30px;
 }
```

Comment: Have you ever tried `margin: 0 auto` ?

Comment: I have not, but I just found the solution. It was to remove the 'container' element. Lol, 48 hours later and the solution was so simple... Thank you @muhammed for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to remove the 'container' element. So simple, yet 2 days worth of eyesight. lol.